# What are the ideal parameters for the width & height of the main layout for widget?

Tags: android-layout

In the case of Widget, if I use RelativeLayout as the main layout, then what will be the best parameters for layout_width & layout_height i.e. whether I have to use "match_parent" or "wrap_content"? Please provide some reference if possible. If the question is below standard then sorry for that.